# Need help giving Abstract Algebra Examples relating to Ideals and Quotient Groups.

Tags: group-theory, ideals

I'm having a hard time trying to provide an example of the following two problems:

1. An example of a ring $R$ and an ideal $I$ of $R$ such that neither $R$ nor $I$ has zero divisors but the quotient group $R/I$ does.
2. A ring $R$, an ideal $I$ of $R$, and an element $r$ in $R - I$ such that $a$ is not idempotent in $R$ but $a + I$ is idempotent in the quotient group $R/I$.

Comment: For both you can take $R$ to be the integers if you pick $I$ with a bit of care (generated by a small but not too small number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1. take $R$ to be $\mathbb Z$ the ring of integers and $I$ to be $6\mathbb Z$. Then $[2],[3]$ are zero divisors in $\mathbb {Z/6Z}$

For 2. take the same $R$ and $I$ then $[4]^2=[4]$ but $4$ is not idempotent in $\mathbb Z$ (same with $3$ and $[3]$)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I forgot 6Z has no zero divisors since it is essentially an enemurable infinite set. I think I overlooked using nZ as an example because I was thinking about Z mod n rather than the a coset of Z itself.